# How click on right click menu in selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

I am trying to click on right click menu and i am able to open the right click menu but its not clicking on any menu or not pressing any keys like down , up etc where i am wrong :

```
profile_pic=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img[class="profilePic img"]')
okl=profile_pic.click()
time.sleep(5)
action1=ActionChains(driver)
action1.context_click(okl).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working version to do it:

> first right click to show up the menu

```
menuDiv = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//<selector>']")
actionChains.move_to_element(menuDiv).perform()
actionChains.context_click().perform()
```

> then locate the submenu item you want to click on

```
time.sleep(3)   //better wait for a little while
targetMenu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//<selector>")
actionChains.click(targetMenu)
actionChains.perform()
```